# Prove that x is in the boundary of A iff x is an accumulation point of the complement of A given x is an isolated point of A

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

The complete question is the following: "Let A be a subset of metric space X and let x be an isolated point of A. Show that x is in the boundary point of A iff x is an accumulation point of $A^C$.

I am having trouble with my proof. I have looked at the proof posted at [isolated point in boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106847/isolated-point-in-boundary?rq=1) and don't understand why the poster's statement "Using the latter fact, we see $x_o$∈Acc($A_c$)" is true. That is, why would having $B_r$(x)∩$A^C$ ≠ Ø imply $B_r$(x)/{x}∩$A^C$ ≠ Ø?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start by using the fact that $x$ is in $A$. In particular, there is an $R>0$ so that $B_r(x) \cap A = \{x\}$ if $r<R$ (i.e. $x$ is the only point in this ball that is in $A$, everything else is in $A^c$).

But, because we're assuming $x \in \partial A$ for this direction, we also know that for *every* $r > 0$, $B_r(x)$ contains points in both $A$ and $A^c$. So, combined with the earlier observation, this means that the rest of the points in $B_R(x)$ (besides $x$) are in $A^c$. In particular, $B_R(x)\backslash\{x\} \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$.